# MySQL or PHP get the sting matches a search string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

How to list the whole string contains a specific substring, for example:

I have the following table in my database

```
| id | title                                       |
| -- | ------------------------------------------- |
| 1  | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text discovered |
| 2  | It is a long established fact that a reader |
```

When I search for `'re'` like:

```
SELECT 'WORD_THAT_CONTAINS re' AS title FROM myTable WHERE title LIKE '%re%'
```

It should return

```
| title      |
| ---------- |
| Lorem      |
| discovered |
| reader     |
```

When I search for `'Lorem Ip'` like:

```
SELECT 'WORD_THAT_CONTAINS Lorem Ip' AS title FROM myTable WHERE title LIKE '%Lorem Ip%'
```

It should return

```
| title       |
| ----------  |
| Lorem Ipsum |
```

How to do it with MySQL or with PHP?

I need this for a online shopping search autocomplete

Comment: If you select a string, it will just return that string.

Comment: I don't need that string what I selected, I need to complete the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use MySQL to get the lines containing the search pattern. Basically this:

```
SELECT title FROM myTable WHERE title LIKE '%Lorem Ip%'
```

Then in PHP you can extract the word, or words, containing the search pattern. Some will try to use regular expressions for this, I prefer normal PHP functions. Something like this:

```
$pattern = 'Lorem Ip';
$title   = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text discovered';

$start  = strpos($title, $pattern);
$finish = $start + strlen($pattern);
while (($start > 0) && ($title[$start] != ' ')) $start--;
while (($finish < strlen($title)) && ($title[$finish] != ' ')) $finish++;

$result = substr($title, $start, $finish - $start);
echo $result;
```

This returns `Lorem Ipsum`. You do this for each result you found. You can fiddle this PHP code no end. Get rid of commas and points, make it multi-byte capable, etc, but the idea is simple.

See: [PHP Sandbox of above code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2acdb1a4cc7404aa5b15b3b4e8ae01a9373af25d)

OK, the above code didn't find the two words for the `re` pattern, so I changed the code to this:

```
// input
$pattern = 're';
$title   = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text discovered';

// cleanup
$words = str_replace(['.',',',';',':'],' ',$title);

// find all full matches
$matches = [];
while ($start = stripos($words,$pattern)) {
    $finish = $start+strlen($pattern);
    while (($start > 0) && ($words[$start] != ' ')) $start--;
    while (($finish < strlen($words)) && ($words[$finish] != ' ')) $finish++;
    $matches[] = trim(substr($words,$start,$finish-$start));
    $words = substr($words,$finish);
}

// output result
var_export($matches);
```

See: [PHP Sandbox of above code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/28f3a40961ef4551a6e8d6786992bc637727ea8b)

Comment: This is a good solution, but I think it will be too expensive  especially on huge data, is there any way with regex?

Comment: It is a misconception that regular expressions are always faster than basic PHP code. In the end a regular expression uses a rather complicated bit of code to do the same thing as you do in normal code. Of course there are some cases in which it is faster or easier to use, no doubt, but I don't think this is one of them. Don't mind to be proven wrong, but don't ask me to write this as a regex. 

Comment: Ah, this solution does not detect two matches in one line. Let me see if I can change that.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like in this website https://www.idealo.de/
try to search for something

Comment: @ferhado Yes, I knew that that was what you were trying. It is true, the bigger the database, the longer the titles, and the shorter the search pattern the more time this will take. You can use a `LIMIT 10` on the query. This way you never get more than 10 result, which makes sure that the code remains fast.

Comment: idealo.de works on a completely different principle, by the way. It first splits up the query into words, and then uses those words to search. You should also think about relevance of results. This could be by popularity of the result, for instance.

Comment: Ok, thank! I will try to do it. If you find any better solution please share it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236823/discussion-between-ferhado-and-kiko-software).